# Deleting comments result as undefined method `comment_path'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When I tried to delete comments, the comments were not deleted from database and there is also an error undefined method `comment_path'...

**_comment.html.erb**

```
 <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
   <%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete %>
 <% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
 def destroy
   @comment.destroy
   flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
   redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
 end
```

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @comments = @micropost.comments
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
link_to(
  "delete",
  microposts_comment_path(comment.micropost, comment),
  method: :delete
)
```

or

```
link_to(
  'Delete Comment',
  [comment.micropost, comment],
  method: :delete,
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
)
```

Comment: Sorry about that @Andrey Deineko .. I'm new at there :)

Comment: You will also be able to upvote others answers/questions when you have enough reputation, 25 or 50, do not remember (you now have 28, try to upvote some answers/questions from now on)

Comment: You are also a good guide for stackoverflow :) @Andrey Deineko

Answer (score 1):

Your `comments` are nested into the scope of `microposts`.

To make it work you have to provide a micropost in the anchor tag.

**Example:**

```
link_to "Delete Comment", [comment.micropost, comment], method: :delete

# OR

link_to "Delete Comment", microposts_comment_path(comment.micropost, comment), method: :delete
```

Comment: Thanks for your guiding :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have nested resources, you have to do as below:

1.In your controller:

```
# DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/1
def destroy
  #1st you retrieve the micropost thanks to params[:micropost_id]
  micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  #2nd you retrieve the comment thanks to params[:id]
  @comment = micropost.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy

  flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end
```

2.In your view, replace

`<%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete %>`

with:

```
<%= link_to "delete", [comment.micropost, comment], method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your guiding :)